# Sort a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, twitter, hashtag

I would like to know which hashtags are used the most in tweets so I did like this

```
cursor = db.execute("SELECT text FROM myTable WHERE text LIKE '%#%' ")
for row in cursor:      
    for word in (re.findall(r"#(\w+)", row[0])):
        top_hashtags.append(word)
top_hashtags = {i:top_hashtags.count(i) for i in set(top_hashtags)}
print sorted(top_hashtags, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

The result was wrong .

I used : `print sorted(top_hashtags, key=lambda x: x[0])` 
But I think it is not working like I want .

Comment: There's no list of dicts here.

Comment: What type is top_hashtags when you enter this bit of code, and why do you rewrite it as a dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) was built for:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(top_hashtags)
print(c.most_common(5)) # print 5 most common hashtags with counts
```

To answer your specific question, to sort dictionary keys by value use:

```
top_ht_dict = {i:top_hashtags.count(i) for i in set(top_hashtags)}

sorted(top_ht_dict, key=top_ht_dict.get, reverse=True)
                                       # ^ most common first
```

Comment: You can use `top_ht_dict.get` as key.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `print sorted(top_hashtags, key=top_hashtags.get, reverse=True)`

This will sort the hashtags according to how many times the hashtag shows up, with the `reverse=True` causing it to be in reverse order (i.e most common hashtags first in the list)